# Add a handler of event for each class which implements the interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, interface

I have this class :

```
Public Class Form1ViewModel

#Region "Classes collègues"
    Public objInfoViewModel As InfoViewModel
    Public objResultViewModel As ResultViewModel
#End Region

#Region "Constructor"
    Public Sub New()
        objInfoViewModel = New InfoViewModel
        objResultViewModel = New ResultViewModel
        Dim collegue As IMediatorForm1
        AddHandler collegue.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
        'AddHandler objInfoViewModel.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
    End Sub
#End Region


#Region "Methods"
    Private Sub OnChangingStatut(ByVal intAge As Integer)
        If (objResultViewModel IsNot Nothing) Then
            If (intAge > 0 AndAlso intAge < 10) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Enfant"
            If (intAge >= 10 AndAlso intAge < 30) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Adolescent"
            If (intAge >= 30 AndAlso intAge < 50) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Homme"
            If (intAge >= 50) Then objResultViewModel.Result = "Vieux"
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

The `InfoViewModel` and `ResultViewModel` are two classes which implements the `IMediatorForm1` interface.

When I try `AddHandler objInfoViewModel.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut` there is no problem.But I'd like to add the handler of event for each class which implements the `IMediatorForm1` interface.

When I try

```
Dim collegue As IMediatorForm1
AddHandler collegue.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
```

I got `Null Exception` because the object `collegue` is nothing. So

1. How Can I fix my Code?
2. What is the best idea to add a handler of an event for each class which implements the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub New()
    objInfoViewModel = New InfoViewModel
    objResultViewModel = New ResultViewModel
    Dim collegue As IMediatorForm1 
    ' you are note setting anything to the object reference above
    AddHandler collegue.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
    ' cannot do the above because "collegue" is NOTHING.
    'AddHandler objInfoViewModel.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
End Sub
```

See comments I added in the code above...

I can propose a solution but it's not really 100% clear what your trying to do.

If the 2 global variables are of that interface type then just use them directly in the AddHandler code.

Alternately you can loop through them to add each one...

```
for each obj as IMediatorForm1 in {objInfoViewModel, objResultViewModel }
    AddHandler obj.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
next
```

***EDIT***

If your trying to hook into the same object your creating that can be done.
Just use "ME" keyword in the constructor.

```
AddHandler Me.ChangeStatut, AddressOf OnChangingStatut
```

Comment: Thanks @DarrenMB : But I know `collegue` is nothing( I mentionned this in my question), I need to know how can I add handler to an event without instanciate a class which implements the interface?

Comment: You cannot add a handler to something that doesn't exist. You require a reference to the object.

Comment: I mean add a handler to ALL classes which implements the interface, your solution is good but I need a global one, I mean if I don't have the full list of classes (`{objInfoViewModel, objResultViewModel,... }`)

Comment: Updated answer. If you truly want a single block of code to process that event for all objects of that type then you  should make the Event Handler subroutine "shared".

Comment: @LamloumiAfif: Not possible. You add handlers to an object. You must have a reference to the object to do anything with it. There is no such thing as "select all objects" in .NET.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what your trying without having to add an AddHandler routine in each class that implements the interface. Interfaces themselves cannot have any real code in them. I have run into this before.

Answer (score 1):

Does your infrastructure permit to use an [abstract class](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fk535acbf%2528v%3Dvs.71%2529.aspx&ei=-siOVOfQD4Lcasa5gsgD&usg=AFQjCNE-MSyX2g4IZ9f_rlq5AqgV7560ug&sig2=Q7ObnVBLt8zHmR98n1D3Fw&bvm=bv.81828268,d.d2s) instead of the `IMediatorForm1` interface? In that case you could implement your handler in an abstract base class.